# Display the SchemaLocation in an XML file using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Very new to XSLT, and I am trying to add the xsi:schemaLocation to my output, however I'm doing something wrong.

This is the xslt code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ems-ag.de/xmlschemas/tst/TEST.XSD http://products.tst.com/tst/TEST.XSD"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.ems-ag.de/xmlschemas/tst/TEST.XSD">

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

Output - Top node gives me this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<TEST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ems-ag.de/xmlschemas/tst/TEST.XSD"
```

Output - However it should give me this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<TEST xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ems-ag.de/xmlschemas/tst/TEST.XSD http://products.tst.com/tst/TEST.XSD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ems-ag.de/xmlschemas/tst/TEST.XSD">
```

Any input as to what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple reason for this is that you're attempting to insert the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute to the document node, not the root element.

Instead of your `<xsl:template match="/">` template, use this:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The root element (`<TEST>` in your example) actually has a parent node, the document itself. As well as being a container for the root element, comments and processing instructions can also be contained within it. Matching `/` matches this document node, not the root element.